# gutenburg array default cause block validation error

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am creating a tab block for my client
I use attribute type array
and it completely work good in save
but after save and refresh the page(in the admin)
it cause the Block validation error
to put it short it just say we save generate the default but post body is what you have saved

the code is this:

```
tabs:{
        type:"array",
        default:[
            {
                id:0,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet0",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                    iconText:[
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit1",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit2",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit3",
                        },
                    ]
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/two-column-option-2-tab-img.jpg"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true
            },
            {
                id:1,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/two-column-option-2-tab-img.jpg"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true
            },//this item will repeat 4 time
},
```

and this is one of the set function and most of my set function are like this

```
    const setTabShapeColor=(value,id)=>{
        console.log(value)
        let currentTabs=attributes.tabs;
        currentTabs[id].shapeColor=value.hex;
        setAttributes({tabs: currentTabs});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution i found is crappy one but it do the job i want
i remove the default value for attribute from attribute and it looks like this:

```
attributes: {
    title: {
        type: "string",
        source: "html",
        selector: "h2",
        default: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
    },
    tabs:{
        type:"array",
    },
```

and instead set default value on eddit function
like this:

```
if(!tabs){
        let defaultTabs =[
            {
                id:0,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet0",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                    iconText:[
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit1",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit2",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit3",
                        },
                    ]
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/two-column-option-2-tab-img.jpg"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true
            },
            {
                id:1,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/two-column-option-2-tab-img.jpg"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true
            },
            {
                id:2,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet2",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                    iconText:[
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit1",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit2",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit3",
                        },
                    ]
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/videoplayback.mp4"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true,
            },
            {
                id:3,
                tabTitle:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet3",
                tabContent:{
                    title:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor",
                    iconText:[
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit1",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit2",
                        },
                        {
                            text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit3",
                        },
                    ]
                },
                tabImage:{
                    nbeDefault: "/two-column-option-2-tab-img.jpg"
                },
                shapeColor:"#00A9E0",
                active:true,
            },
        ];
        setAttributes({tabs: defaultTabs});
    }
```

and every where i want to show my tabs whether it is on eddit or save
i checked if it is true or has value like this

```
{
tabs?tabs.map((y)=>{.....}:""
}
```